# How to try/catch in a child function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I have 2 functions, a parent and a child - what is the best practice/way to handle errors when using a `try/catch` block?

In the below example I have 2 functions, child and parent, both with `try/catch` blocks.

Is it good/best I remove the try/catch block from the child, as if an error happens, it will be passed to the parents `try/catch`, then show the error? (Or is there a better way?)

```js
async function childFunc() {
    try {
      await query1()
      await query2()
    } catch(err) {
      throw err
    }
}

async function parentFunc() {
    try {   
      await childFunc()   
    } catch(err) {   
      console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't catch the error if you're not going to do anything about it. Catching and re-throwing is equivalent to just not catching.

Comment: Depends on what you need. In your current code, catching `err` in `childFunc` is pointless, because you are just re-throwing it. If you want to do some special error handling inside `childFunc` you may need to catch the error there ...

Comment: @VLAZ - that just isn't correct. Catching and rethrowing is a common pattern when you're building a layered architecture. For example, you should't allow database errors to propagate through the UI layer to the user. Instead you would catch the db error and throw a different error giving the client some clue on how to proceed (try again later, give up, change the input data, etc.).

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer and is this code throwing a *different* error? It isn't. The term "re-throw" is used when throwing *the same* exception. That's what the code is doing. Wraps the code in a useless `try`/`catch`.

Comment: @VLAZ -- accepted. Catch and rethrow without extra handling is pointless.

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ and @Software Engineer, so the consensus is unless I do something with the error in the child - I should just have a child function without a `try/catch`.

Comment: Yes. If you cannot react in any way to the error, then don't `try`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only catch errors if you can do anything at all about them. Maybe log some extra information at the very least or throw a different error later.

If you cannot react in any way to the error, then don't `try`.